# Do quasiparticles have antiparticles?

Tags: antimatter

Bosons (except for W) are their own antiparticles, since they have no electric charge. Charged fermions have antiparticles differing from the particles.

Now my question is: has a charged quasiparticle (polaron, etc.) an antiparticle?

Comment: Fuzzy. You should look first to http://www.particleadventure.org/fermibos.html to understand fermions and bosons.

Comment: Now I understand - you speak about 'composite bosons', mesons, where $\pi^+$ is anti to $\pi^-$. But B/F statistics is about spins, not bout antiparticle properties...$^{4}He$ is boson.

Comment: I just wanted to know if the mathematical QFT concept describing particles and antiparticles can also be applied to quasiparticles. Sorry, my question sounded a bit confusing.

Comment: I dont think. To my knowledge, these are usually used as a concept to describe some property in solid physics (or elsewhere). They are no real particles and all depends then on the definition. Anti-qp could be a 'destruction operator' of qp...

Comment: Some quasiparticles have antiparticles, and some quasiparticles act as their own antiparticles, just like ordinary particles. Charged quasiparticles will have antiparticles with opposite charge; uncharged quasiparticles may or may not be their own antiparticles.